# I can't get video screenshots in iOS5 using AVAssetImageGenerator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer

I need to get screenshots from a video.

I'm using the following method:

```
- (UIImage *)screenshotFromPlayerItem:(AVPlayerItem *)player atTime:(CMTime)time
{
    CMTime actualTime;
    NSError *error;

    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:player.asset];

     CGImageRef cgIm = [generator copyCGImageAtTime:time
                                    actualTime:&actualTime
                                         error:&error];
     UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgIm];

    if (nil != error)
   {
       NSLog(@"Error making screenshot: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
       return nil;
   }

    CFRelease(cgIm);

   return image;
}
```

In iOS6 it works perfect. But if i test on a device (iPhone and an iPad) with iOS5 i get the following message: "Error making screenshot: Cannot Decode"

The video is mp4.

Any solution?

Comment: It's because i have 4 AVPlayers. I can't get screenshots from them if i have more than 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using to many media actions (i have 4 AVPlayer) and that's why it doesn't work!